# Why method "div" is faster thant "div2"?

Tags: ruby, time-complexity

Im trying to decipher why the `div` method is faster than the `div2` method, and I cant find the reason.

```
def div2(num)
  [*1..num].select do |n|
    n if num % n == 0
  end
end

 p div2(58463982)
```

```
def div(num)
 result = []
 (1..num).each do |n|
   break if result.include?(num / n)
   result.concat([n, num / n]).uniq! if num % n == 0
 end
 result.sort!
end

p div(58463982)
```

Comment: Try both methods by hand for a much smaller number, say 15. div2 will loop 15 times, div will loop until 5, sees that it has found 5 already (when it divided by 3) and breaks.

Comment: Still better would be looping until the [integer square root](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Integer.html#method-c-sqrt) of num.

Answer (score 2):

I will let others explain why `div` is faster than `div2`. I want to show how to compute the factors of the given natural number in a way that is considerably faster.

Every integer can be expressed as the product of a collection of prime numbers, each taken to a power of one or more. We can use the method [Prime::prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division) to obtain those prime numbers and powers. For example,

```
require 'prime'
```

```
arr = Prime.prime_division(58463982)
  #=> [[2, 1], [3, 2], [53, 1], [61283, 1]]
```

This means that:

```
(2**1) * (3**2) * (53**1) * (61283**1)
  #=> 58463982
```

One divisor of `58463982` equals, for example:

```
(2**1) * (3**2) * (53**0) * (61283**1)
  #=> 2 * 9 * 1 * 61283
  #=> 1103094
```

To confirm:

```
58463982 % 1103094
  #=> 0
```

Another would be

```
(2**0) * (3**1) * (53**1) * (61283**0)
  #=> 1 * 3 * 53 * 1
  #=> 159
```

We find that all factors of a given number can be computed (combinatorially) as follows, using the methods [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product) and [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a. `inject`).

```
def all_factors(n)
  primes, exponents = Prime.prime_division(n).transpose
  first_exp_range, *rest_exp_range = exponents.map { |e| [*0..e] }
  first_exp_range.product(*rest_exp_range).map do |exps| 
    primes.zip(exps).reduce(1) { |t,(p,e)| t*(p**e) }
  end.sort
end
```

Depending on requirements, `.sort` at the end may not be required.

---

We may test:

```
require 'time'
```

```
t = Time.now
p all_factors(58463982)
p Time.now - t
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 53, 106, 159, 318, 477, 954, 61283, 122566,
  #    183849, 367698, 551547, 1103094, 3247999, 6495998, 9743997,
  #    19487994, 29231991, 58463982]
  #
  #=> 0.001405 (seconds)
```

By constrast, computing the factors of `58463982` with `div2` and `div` required `4.467112` and `0.021103` seconds, respectively.

This is clearly much faster than those methods.

---

We may step through the example to view the calculations being performed.

```
n = 58463982
```

then

```
primes, exponents = Prime.prime_division(n).transpose
  #=> [[2, 3, 53, 61283], [1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

so

```
primes
  #=> [2, 3, 53, 61283]
exponents
  #=> [1, 2, 1, 1]
```

Then,

```
first_exp_range, *rest_exp_range = exponents.map { |e| [*0..e] }
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

so

```
first_exp_range
  #=> [0, 1]
rest_exp_range
  #=> [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1]
```

Then

```
a = first_exp_range.product(*res_exp_range)
  #=> [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1, 1],
  #    [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1],
  #    [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

Then,

```
 b = a.map { |exps| primes.zip(exps).reduce(1) { |t,(p,e)| t*(p**e) } }
   #=> [1, 61283, 53, 3247999, 3, 183849, 159, 9743997, 9, 551547,
   #    477, 29231991, 2, 122566, 106, 6495998, 6, 367698, 318,
   #    19487994, 18, 1103094, 954, 58463982]
```

To view the result sorted,

```
b.sort
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 53, 106, 159, 318, 477, 954, 61283, 122566,
  #    183849, 367698, 551547, 1103094, 3247999, 6495998, 9743997,
  #    19487994, 29231991, 58463982]
```

Comment: "in part because Prime::prime_division is written in optimized C code." In the end, it is all C in Matz's Ruby off course but the  "toggle source" button in the docs shows only plain old Ruby.

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/prime/blob/5f96c1e051c2e72f22e7fc11a36bf2f997b4222f/lib/prime.rb#L303-L327

Comment: @steenslag and...

Answer (score 1):

The `div2` method create a list from `1` to `num` then iterates over all of the elements in it.

The `div` method can break early, and so does not have to iterate as many times.